# React Reusable Components with Next.js Shallow Routing Updates URL, but on Refresh, 404

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-hooks, next.js

I have a list of projects on the left side, and when you click on a project, the details show up on the right. I've done this where I have a reusable component of `Details.js` being rendered without a page refresh and updating the URL with Next.js shallow routing.

Idea:

[image]

`/pages/projects/index.js`

```
const Projects = () => {
  const { user } = useUser();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
  const [projectSelectedId, setProjectSelectedId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) return null;

    const fetchProjects = async () => {
      // this is where I get my projects data
    };
    fetchProjects();
  }, [user]);

  const handleProject = (data) => {
    const pid = data.id;
    setProjectSelectedId(pid);
    router.push("/projects/", `/projects/${pid}`, { shallow: true });
  };
  if (!user) return null;

  return (
    <>
      {user && (
        <div>
          <div>
            <h1>Projects</h1>
            <div>
              {projects &&
                projects.map((project, index) => (
                  <div key={index}>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => handleProject(projects[index])}
                    >
                      {project.title}
                    </button>
                  </div>
                ))}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            {projectSelectedId && (
              <Details pid={projectSelectedId} />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Projects;
```

When a project is selected, the URL gets updated when I use shallow routing:

```
router.push("/projects/", `/projects/${pid}`, { shallow: true });
```

This works fine, but when I refresh the page, I get 404. I want it to go to the selected project with the details on refresh as well.

Comment: Does the navigation works without `shallow routing`?

Comment: @RyanLe no, the components just get updated, without URL change, but I want to have URL with id so the proper details show up

Comment: I see, why don't you put your `Details` component on a separate page? This is not a proper way to do navigation on Nextjs

Comment: @RyanLe I wanted to be able to have the user go through the projects without refreshing the page for faster loading, and at the same time, updating the URL, and if the user accidentally refreshes, it go to the previous project details the user was looking at

Comment: Nextjs does routing does not cause re-rendering if you set it up properly. If you want to stick with your solution, I'll post an answer for it.?

Comment: @RyanLe I wasn't too sure on how to approach the routing situation, perhaps the shallow routing I did was wrong. I just wanted to update the URL path, but keep the list of projects like it hasn't been refreshed, and then only update the Details component with proper id to render correct information. If you have a better solution, I'm all ears.

Comment: Yeah, Just want to clarify before a put a proper answer for this. You basically want to navigate to `projects` without refreshing the `layout` right?

Comment: @RyanLe yup! at the same time having the proper url to navigate to the correct project detail

Comment: Sure, I'm going to give you an example

Comment: I've put an example down below, you could follow that and have an idea to set up your app, let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Your approach has a few issues, and you would need to set up a proper layout for your nextjs app**

**Something like this:**

- In your _app.js:

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

- As in your layout.js

```
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <Sidebar />
        {children}
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

- Sidebar for navigation:

```
export default function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <nav className={styles.nav}>
      <Link href="/">
        <a>Index</a>
      </Link>
      <Link href="/project/1">
        <a>Project 1</a>
      </Link>
      <Link href="/project/2">
        <a>Project 2</a>
      </Link>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

- And so on to your project pages, you will need a structure like so:

[image]

---

### **Checkout the full example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vristt?devtoolsheight=33&file=pages/project1.js)**

Comment: I think I kind of get it. Do I need to wrap my entire application with Layout component? How do I just wrap <Layout> around a specific page, like `/project/index.js` not sure if this makes any sense? Because the sidebar is only showing up when user navigates to `localhost:3000/project/`

Comment: Yeah, you can modify the above example to your needs. wrap your entire app with a layout and have some conditions to show it. Use `useRouter` as I did in `[id].js` to decide when to show it.

Comment: Sorry, it was late last night and I fell asleep. This didn't solve my exact problem, but it did guide me to a new path that I'll try to figure out, thank you!

Comment: Feel free to raise questions if you need to. I’ll try to help

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get it to working! I appreciate your help!